# Prism and TabControl and TabIndex

Tags: silverlight, prism, tabcontrol

I want to put views in the same order into a TabControl every time. Now the order of my tabs is random, bacause of the loading of the modules, I gues. 
How to setup the TabIndex if I use TabControl as a region with prism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a ViewSortHint attribute on your view concrete class and prism will sort your views/tabs in the same order as the sort hint describes